Is it possible to change the %APP_NAME% inside email verification template in firebase auth?
I know that Firebase doesn't allow you to change the email content for security purposes, but is there a way I could have multiple %APP_NAME%? I tried to setup multiple apps inside my project and I tried to send the email verification from those apps upon registration, but the %APP_NAME% wasn't replaced with the app nickname and it didn't work properly.
EDIT: We have multiple websites that use the same project, consider x and y as different websites and x as the main one: When the user registers through x, they would receive the correct %APP_NAME&, but when they register through y, they are receiving the %APP_NAME% of x, which is annoying because they didn't register through x.

This has been covered before, so I linked a few of the previous questions. If the solutions offered there don't work for you, edit your question to show what you did. That will also make your question eligible for reopening.

@FrankvanPuffelen Thank you Frank, these are not duplicates because they're asking how they can change the %APP_NAME% while my post is asking how I can include multiple %APP_NAME%-s for each of the websites. I updated the post to clarify this.

Re-opened, but what you want isn't possible. If you want to use different app names, you'll need to put each web site in its own project.

A single Firebase project currently has only one app name, so what you want isn't possible in Firebase Hosting/Authentication. If you want to use a different app name for each web site, you'll need to put each web site in its own Firebase project. If you want to have all web sites in one Firebase project, you'll have to come up with a single app name to cover them all.
Firebase logic typically recommends to use one project per logo or app name. So putting variants of the same app (e.g. multiple languages, or pro and non-pro versions) of an app in a single project works, but putting multiple disjunct apps into a single project doesn't.

Is it completely impossible? Can we use some 3rd party app like mailgun to send a custom email that includes the oobCode or is it also not possible?

If you use a third-party mailer, you can do pretty much whatever you want. But it's not the registered app name in Firebase anymore at that point.
